# Python repeating a function n times repeats the same one

Tags: python, loops, random

I have this code that randomly selects an item in the list and matches each other following a rule. I would like to repeat the matches N times, and count how many events occurred stored in variables tie and diff.

The problem is that, at the moment, it repeats N times the same results, not a different match. If I sate range(10) it will repeat the same match result 10 times. I would like to repeat the match N times, not the same result.

```
import random

rules = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
pc1 = random.choices(rules)
pc2 = random.choices(rules)
tie = 0
diff = 0

def match():
    if pc1 == pc2:
        return False
        print('tie')
    if pc1 != pc2:
        return True
        print('different') 

for _ in range(10):
    if match() == False:
        tie +=1
    if match() == True:
        diff +=1
    
print(tie, diff)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You choose pc1 and pc2 randomly just once. To select random element from list **each time** you should use `random.choices` inside your function `match`.
2. You should use `random.choice` if you want to get an element. While `random.choices` returns a list like `['rock']`, `random.choice` will return the element itself, e.g. `'rock'`.
3. You call your function twice in for loop, which causes `random.choice` to be called twice with possibly different results. A solution is to put the function call result in a variable (like `match_result = match()`) and then compare it in `if`.

With these considerations, the code can look like this:

```
import random

rules = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
tie = 0
diff = 0


def match():
    pc1 = random.choice(rules)
    pc2 = random.choice(rules)
    if pc1 == pc2:
        return False
        print('tie')
    if pc1 != pc2:
        return True
        print('different')


for _ in range(10):
    match_result = match()
    if match_result == False:
        tie += 1
    if match_result == True:
        diff += 1

print(tie, diff)
```

Comment: thanks! Would it possible to know how many times which pairs were chosen?

Comment: If you mean to count ties and diffs, it's done already. If you mean to count how many times **each possible pair** was chosen (['rock', 'scissors'], ['paper', 'paper']... etc), its a bit trickier, but possible. Please, specify

Comment: Should we treat `['rock', 'paper']` and `['paper', 'rock']` as same or as different pairs?

Comment: I'd say as different combination